# Site only works if .php is added to the files can someone help write rule for pages?

Tags: php, database, .htaccess

So I have a php site, here: http://driveusatruck.com/homepage/about.php that page for instance ONLY works if you manually add .php to the end of the file, which is fine, but when you browse around to other pages of the site, you'll see that they don't work. Is it possible to create a re-write somehow to get around this, so that if went to /about for instance, things would work fine?

This was a site that someone on my team transferred from an old host, which they claim does not require a database... the weird thing is that if you go here:  http://driveusatruck.com/homepage/  there is some verbiage about a database being required.... Does anyone know if that's the case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've typically used

```
###########################
 # Remove trailing slash on non-directories
 ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

###########################
 # 301 /index.php to /
 ##
RewriteRule (.*)/index(\.[a-zA-Z]+)*$ $1 [L,R=301]

###########################
 # 301 .php requests
 ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[a-z0-9-]+\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

###########################
 # Rewrite file -> file.php
 ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ $1.php [L]
```